Why doesn't this simple code link with Winmm.lib
I'm using Windows 10 with 64 bit system and I am trying to play mp3 audio file using C++. I sourced my lines of code from answer to this question. And the entire main file is as follows:
#include<Windows.h>

int main()
{
    mciSendString("open \"Test.mp3\" type mpegvideo alias mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
    mciSendString("play mp3", NULL, 0, NULL);
}

As a compiler I use G++ and I build the program using this command g++ -lWinmm main.cpp.
I expected this code to compile and play a short sample sound stored in Test.mp3, but compilation fails and the following is the output to the console.
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\ccic5o7r.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `__imp_mciSendStringA'
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Temp\ccic5o7r.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__imp_mciSendStringA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My editor shows that the function mciSendString expands to mciSendStringW which is bit weird in my opinion because the console output mentions the function mciSendStringA but it does not matter as whether I explicitly use mciSendStringW or mciSendStringA in my main function, the error stays unchanged. Microsoft's page says that the function is from library Winmm.lib and exactly that one I'm additionally linking against in my G++ compilation command.
The actual Winmm.lib files do exist in the directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22000.0\um\x64 but their names in reality are capitalized like this WinMM.Lib, which is strange because in the aforementioned Microsoft's page tells that the filename is Winmm.lib. Alas the capitalization didn't make any difference. I additionally used -L flag with G++ to specify the directory where the file is but this did nothing because G++ looks at this folder for lib files by default.
I am out of ideas why this code won't compile. Sincerely hope someone can come up with plausible explanation why. I'm ready to answer any additional questions.

Pretty sure it's supposed to be g++ test.cpp -lWinmm, order matters

@john Yep that was it. Now I feel stupid for writing this long and detailed question.

As @john mentioned in a comment to my question, the order of g++ command arguments and flags matters. I should have written g++ main.cpp -lWinmm instead of g++ -lWinmm main.cpp. Good read on the topic is the answer to this question.
